# Parsing my SWIFT Dictionary

Tags: ios, json, swift, dictionary, firebase

I am querying a JSON database of zombies and it returns them as a Dictionary.  I don't know how to mutate it with SWIFT 3

Here's the query::

```
func getZombieAttackGroupFromDatabase () {
        ref?.child("Attacker Group").child((self.userParty?.leadID)!).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
            // Get data
            print("PULLING DATA")
            if let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary{

                // break data into an Array of Zombie Structs

          //      print(value)

                for zombieID in value.allKeys {
                    print(value[zombieID])

                    let thisZombieID = zombieID
                    let thisZombieGroup = value[zombieID]["Group"]
                }



            } else {

            }
            // ...
        }) { (error) in
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }


}
```

this part: let thisZombieGroup = value[zombieID]["Group"] isn't being recognized.  How do I access group?  If i get that, i can modify to the other components.

Here's the return :

```
{
    "-KrNSmv64Ia32g5nw1L9" =     {
        Group = 15;
        Health = 250;
        "Is Undead" = true;
        Location = 1;
        Number = 0;
    };
    "-KrNSmv64Ia32g5nw1LA" =     {
        Group = 11;
        Health = 250;
        "Is Undead" = true;
        Location = 5;
        Number = 1;
    };
    "-KrNSmv64Ia32g5nw1LB" =     {
        Group = 2;
        Health = 250;
        "Is Undead" = true;
        Location = 3;
        Number = 2;
    };
    "-KrNSmv776r9eO6t7CY0" =     {
        Group = 14;
        Health = 250;
        "Is Undead" = true;
        Location = 0;
        Number = 3;
    };
    "-KrNSmv776r9eO6t7CY1" =     {
        Group = 0;
        Health = 250;
        "Is Undead" = true;
        Location = 4;
        Number = 4;
    };
}
```

As you can see, each of the Structs has a parent that is an automatically generated ID. I don't know how to access it.

How can I access each element from item 1? I need the parent auto-key "-KrNSmv64Ia32g5nw1L9" and each child value.

```
"-KrNSmv64Ia32g5nw1L9" =     {
        Group = 15;
        Health = 250;
        "Is Undead" = true;
        Location = 1;
        Number = 0;
```

Comment: Are you asking how to parse JSON into structs (and using the root string of each element as an attribute for each struct) ? Or how to access a dictionary structure without knowing the keys beforehand ?

Comment: updated my query

Comment: Make print(value[zombieID]). What values will you get?

Comment: each time I run it I get different zombies, so the data won't match, but the code is the same:  here's the output       Optional({
    Group = 6;
    Health = 250;
    "Is Undead" = true;
    Location = 5;
    Number = 1;
})
Optional({
    Group = 11;
    Health = 250;
    "Is Undead" = true;
    Location = 1;
    Number = 0;
})
Optional({
    Group = 1;
    Health = 250;
    "Is Undead" = true;
    Location = 4;
    Number = 3;
})
Optional({
    Group = 10;
    Health = 250;
    "Is Undead" = true;
    Location = 2;
    Number = 2;
})

Comment: print(thisZombieID) returns exactly what I wanted.  I just need the sub-level data ::: -KrNeL-emFB62OyXfBXy
-KrNeL-emFB62OyXfBXx
-KrNeL-emFB62OyXfBY-
-KrNeL-dL_MwsXyTlp0-
-KrNeL-emFB62OyXfBXz

Answer (score 2):

Cast `value` to a proper Swift dictionary, not `NSDictionary`.

`if let value = snapshot.value as? [String:Any]`.

You just have to iterate through the keys of the dictionaries, get the embedded dictionary using the key value and then parse the "zombie data".

```
for key in value.keys {
    if let zombieData = value[key] as? [String:Any] {
        zombieData
        if let group = zombieData["Group"] as? Int, let health = zombieData["Health"] as? Int, let isUndead = zombieData["Is Undead"] as? Bool, let location = zombieData["Location"] as? Int, let number = zombieData["Number"] as? Int {
            //use the parsed data
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i just updated the post to include the query.  I don't have it the way you do.  Any thoughts on how to modify my closure?

Comment: Use of unresolved identifier 'jsonResponse'  Do I need to initiatize jsonResponse somehow?  I've never seen that before.

Comment: i also had to modify your first line to value.allKeys because it was an NSDictionary

Comment: I just forgot to update `jsonResponse` to `value`, check it now. And as you can see it in my answer, __do not__ use `NSDictionary` in Swift. Cast `value` to a Swift dictionary as you can see it in my answer.

Comment: at first it did nothing, so i took all of the lets out of the closure and removed the if statement.  It now prints "nil" for each item

Comment: I copied the dictionary into a playground and this code worked perfectly.You should make the let statements into separate if clauses and see which one doesn't work, maybe the the data type of one of the properties isn't exactly what it looks like to be.

Comment: I probably missed a small detail.  I learned a good bit from what you showed.  I'd never even noticed I could convert formats at the beginning like that.  Now I know, and knowing is half the battle.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
               for zombieID in value.allKeys {
                    print(value[zombieID])

                    let thisZombieID = zombieID
                    if let zombieValues = value[zombieID] as? [String:Any] {
                         let thisZombieGroup = zombieValues["Group"] as? Int
                    }
                }
```

Comment: printed Nil for all thisZombieGroup

Comment: when I did that I added a print(thisZombieGroup) and got nil for all values

Comment: It seems that your value is String, not dictionary.
Try this if let zombieValues = value[zombieID] as? String {
                         print(zombieValues)
                    }
If this code will print something like this: "Group = 6; Health = 250; "Is Undead" = true; Location = 5; Number = 1;" so this will be a String for sure

Comment: -KrNhJN_Wd-9hHfigioV
["Health": 250, "Group": 21, "Number": 2, "Location": 5, "Is Undead": true]
-KrNhJN_Wd-9hHfigioU
["Health": 250, "Group": 10, "Number": 1, "Location": 4, "Is Undead": true]
-KrNhJNZiTMwfMaARqPI
["Health": 250, "Group": 23, "Number": 0, "Location": 3, "Is Undead": true]
-KrNhJN_Wd-9hHfigioX
["Health": 250, "Group": 21, "Number": 4, "Location": 2, "Is Undead": true]
-KrNhJN_Wd-9hHfigioW
["Health": 250, "Group": 21, "Number": 3, "Location": 0, "Is Undead": true]

Comment: with 2 prints, the first is the ID, the second is the zombiegroup.

Comment: for zombieID in value.allKeys {
                        let thisZombieID = zombieID
                        print(thisZombieID)
                        if let zombieValues = value[zombieID] as? [String:Any] {
                            let thisZombieGroup = zombieValues["Group"]
                            print(thisZombieGroup)
                        }
                    }

Comment: the above code gave me the correct value, but it's in the form Optional(14)  Any idea how to get rid of the optional part?

Comment: here's the current print result :  -KrNjU4oONjTK2Eef6_5
Optional(22)
-KrNkkJ_3WO7Xka0xpkY
Optional(21)
-KrNkWCPFNuI3hOeIxg1
Optional(4)
-KrNkWCQ3jhLVknbbTFu
Optional(12)

Comment: Interesting, never seen that issue before, it seems that it can't downcast to Int or something that I can't understand. Try those options: 1) let thisZombieGroup = (zombieValues["Group"] as? Double) ?? 0 2) let thisZombieGroup: Int = zombieValues["Group"] ?? 0 3) let thisZombieGroup: Double = zombieValues["Group"] ?? 0

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151805/discussion-between-mason-ballowe-and-woof).

Comment: converting it to an int after it was pulled as a string got rid of the "optional" problem.

Answer (score 0):

First, Thank you so much to Woof and David.  It was a combination of both of your ideas that got it to work.

```
    func getZombieAttackGroupFromDatabase () {
            ref?.child("Attacker Group").child((self.userParty?.leadID)!).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
                // Get data
                print("PULLING DATA")
                if let value = snapshot.value as? [String:Any]{

                    // break data into an Array of Zombie Structs

                    for zombieID in value.keys {
                        let thisZombieID = zombieID
                        print(thisZombieID)

                        let zombieValues = value[zombieID] as? [String:Any]

                        let thisZombieGroup = zombieValues?["Group"] as! String
                        print(thisZombieGroup)

                    }
                } else {

                }
                // ...
            }) { (error) in
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is good, but be careful with unwrapping zombieValues, because if there will be error with data, you will have fatal error then. Use: if let thisZombieGroup = zombieValues?["Group"] as? String {
}

Or set a default values for that situation: let thisZombieGroup = (zombieValues?["Group"] as? String) ?? ""